# ABI compilance check for libraries version with the exception of Namespace

Tags: c++, abi

I am using abi-compiance-checker (https://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/ ) utility to check the two versions on same libraries and fetching list of incompatibilities if any. And it is working fine.

Now, after a specific version, because of some reason, we are planning to change the namespace of classes in this library. (This will make it incompatible with previous versions, that is acceptable).

Now, I want to use abi compliance checker to make sure that there is no other symbol mismatch.

```
e.g. 
Accpetable:
Version1: lib.so : int OLD_NAMESPACE::func_name (int a, int b);
Version2: lib.so : int NEW_NAMESPACE::func_name (int a, int b);

Not-acceptble:
Version1: lib.so : int OLD_NAMESPACE::func_name (int a, int b);
Version2: lib.so : int NEW_NAMESPACE::func_name (int a, int b, int c);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Temporarily rename the namespace, build, check compliance, then undo the rename?

Comment: Have you tried [skip_namespaces](https://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/Xml-Descriptor.html)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, these are 100s of libraries managed by various developers, so this experiment is not possible.

Comment: But renaming the namespaces in those 100s of libraries was possible in the first place?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, :( , hard world

Comment: @AlanBirtles, this option seems to disable the check for the given namespace.

Comment: So you want to check the abi is compatible in your broken abi? That doesn't make much sense to me?